# Make form stay in front of other windows without resizing or moving it

Tags: c#, winforms, overlap, topmost

I have a simple project that is basically a little clock that should stay on the lower left corner of the screen, and i want it to stay in front of all other windows at all times, but I have now idea how to make that. Is there any property or class I should use? It also shouldn't prevent the user from interacting with other windows.

Comment: Have you tried setting the TopMost property on the window property on VS? It should keep it in front while allowing u to use other windows.

Comment: What if someone else wrote the same program?  Who wins the Most-On-Top race?  Doesn't work.  See [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)

Comment: The world if full of `If`s ;) doesn't mean it all race against each other.

Comment: Well, the TopMost worked, thanks Prix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `.TopMost = true` property.